# Embedding flash player within a image link

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed

I'm struggling to place this small script within my website.

I want to display a small image of a play button and then once its clicked for it to load up or start the stream. Sure there is an easy way to do this but Can't seem to find any other posts that solve my problem.

```
<script>
                // MixStream Flash Player, http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/
                var flashvars = {};flashvars.serverHost = "87.106.143.80:8000/stream/2/";flashvars.getStats = "1";flashvars.autoStart = "1";flashvars.textColour = "";flashvars.buttonColour = "";var params = {};params.bgcolor= "";params.wmode="transparent";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/v1.3.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#video')fadeIn();
    });`

Comment: How exactly do I apply this to embed the video?

Comment: Using javascript, include jQuery and then include that code. Then create a button with the class of 'button' and wrap the video in a 'video' id.